# Facebook share via iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a couple of share buttons as regular links to [http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (as an example). I know, it is an old method, but it works fine.

But how can I open such links in iframe (not in new window) with lightbox, fancybox etc? I have just tested this way, but it doesnt work propretly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to change the page inside an `iframe` then you can use:

```
<iframe id="fb"></iframe>

page = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?etc";
document.getElementById('fb').src = page;
```

That's a simplistic example.

Comment: the problem is that facebook (also twitter, vkontakte) doesnt allow to load its share page in iframe.

Comment: so what is it you want to do?

Comment: I want to open this url in iframe.

Comment: so you want to parse the address out of the URL? (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)